# Как можно вывести данные датчика с сайта narodmon? python

Tags: python-3.x

Я хочу вывести данные датчика с сайта narodmon.ru . Вариант парсинга отпадает потому, что в коде сайта этот элемент не состоит ни в каком классе. Я искал инфу в гугле, находил только на других языках (а надо python), для своего датчика и для системы умных домов. Если кто-то сможет разобраться, буду презнателен.

Comment: Гугл говорит, что у них есть апи. По идее, вам нужно сначала выполнить первые два пункта отсюда: https://alexstar.ru/web/smarthome/ozvuchivaem-pokazaniia-datchikov-s-narodmon-ru-cherez-domovyonka-kuziu После чего у вас будет GET-запрос, которым вы сможете тягать нужные данные.

Comment: @Xander а как достать GET запрос? Я просто только начинаю разбираться в питон и не все знаю.

Comment: В той же инструкции в третьем пункте есть шаблон, по которому нужно составить URL. После того, как у вас будет URL, гуглите "как сделать get-запрос из питона".

Comment: @Xander, я составил ссылку, но не могу понять, что нужно вставить в пробел "здесь произвольный идентификатор"

Comment: @Xander, все я создал ссылку спасибо за помощь. Осталось только разобраться с гет